# What exactly does this mean Collection<? extends E> c

Tags: java, javadoc

Some times, well a lot of times I see this thing occurring in the documentation. It leaves me wondering what to type. Could someone explain to me the meaning of this in clear dumbed down text :D. How this:

```
ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

end up to be used as this:

```
new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a","b","c"));
```

so I don't need to ask this "question" anymore by googling it, but being able to figure it out by myself.

Comment: Take a look at the [Oracle Tutorial on Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html). You may want to read the whole chapter, since generics in Java can be pretty messy. Also, look up the [PECS Mnemonic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The syntax `? extends E` means "some type that either is E or a subtype of E".  The `?` is a wildcard.

The code `Arrays.asList("a","b","c")` is inferred to return a `List<String>`, and `new ArrayList<>` uses the diamond operator, so that yields an `ArrayList<String>`.

The wildcard allows you to infer a subtype -- you could assign it to a reference variable with a supertype:

```
List<CharSequence> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a","b","c"));
```

Here, `E` is inferred as `CharSequence` instead of `String`, but that works, because `String` is a subtype of `CharSequence`.

Comment: Thank you, understanding +1

Comment: "some type that either is E or a subtype of E"  how is `Collection<? extends E> c` different from just writing `Collection c`?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> testList1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a","b","c"));
```

This statement creates an entirely new ArrayList object that contains the same elements as the list generated using Arrays.asList("a","b","c").

Therefore, the new ArrayList and the original String list are completely independent objects.

FYI : Arrays.asList(arrAgument);
This creates a immutable/ unmodifiable list.We cannot be altered by adding or removing items because the underlying String array's length cannot be changed at run time. if you try to do add or remove a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException will be thrown at run time.